# Hide Rows when a specific string is in a cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a problem with VBA in Excel 2007.
I need a macro to hide rows when a specific string is in a cell. (e.g. "System PPP cancelled")

My macro:

```
Sub HideRows()  
    Dim Cell As Range  
    If InStr(Cell, "cancelled") And Rows(Cell.Row).Hidden = False _  
    Then Rows(Cell.Row).Hidden = True  
    Next Cell  
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I get the runtime-error '13'...
Can you help me?

Comment: My VBA is a little rusty, but I think that there are a few mistakes in your code; don't If statements require an end if statement to match?

Comment: Also further to Philip's question, there are **Next Cell** which implies there should be a loop going through the range?  Here's an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @PhilipAdler Generally yes, but not if the entire statement is contained on a single line, as in the case above.

Comment: You will need to put a `For Each` loop, but that will require defining the range over which you're iterating. Please provide more explanation/detail in your original question.

Comment: Can't you use an autofilter?

Comment: @Rory I would try to tackle this one with the `.AutoFilter` too, I think I'm going to change my username to `MrAutoFilter` hahaha

Comment: Also the question is do you want to hide the row exactly after the text is entered into the cell or after clicking on some button?

Comment: I want to show/hide the rows with a click on some button: Rory and Dan Wagner: Autofilter is a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Excel 2010:

```
Sub hide_cancelled()
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
If InStr(Cells(i, 2).value, "cancelled") And Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
    Rows(i).Hidden = True
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Note that this will iterate over ALL rows in the spreadsheet, no matter if they contain any data or completely empty. This may take a while! So instead of `Rows.Count` you should enter a more sane value.

Also this will expect the search value in column 2. Change this in `Cells(i,xxx)`

Comment: Thanks, the code works very well. Notice: "End If" don't work with Excel 2007, Excel get an error with "no if statement" or so...